# How do I animate/interpolate between two CSS values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, interpolation

The following code is working fine, but I'm looking for a way to animate/interpolate between the two creating a slide effect. How can I achieve this?

(I need to have the odd click function as is probably because of how the rest of the site works, otherwise I would have used the jqueryUI slide function)

```
$('.boxbtn').on('click', function () {
    var boxwidth = $('.box').width();
    console.log(boxwidth);
    console.log('-' + boxwidth + 'px');

    var oddClick = $(this).data("oddClick");
    $(this).data("oddClick", !oddClick);
    if (oddClick) {

        $(".box").css('margin-left', ('-' + boxwidth + 'px'));
    }

});
```

Comment: use animate() instead of css()

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński That seem to make it do nothing at all instead?

Comment: Maybe put an example on jsfiddle. There are many things which are not clear here.

Comment: @AdamMoszczyński I don't think 'margin-left' works with .animate(), but I solved it with a simple 'transition: all .15s ease-in-out;' in the css instead. Works fine for what I need it to do – thank you for your help though!

Comment: it works but you need to use 'marginLeft' instead of 'margin-left'. Good you made it work though.